# onnx graph, how to get output dimensions?

Tags: python-3.x, onnx

How to get dimensions of output layers in onnx neural net?

I can get onnx graph, but there is no output dimensions:

```
~/onnx-tensorrt/third_party/onnx/onnx/tools/net_drawer.py --input ./weights/tiny_3l_v5_11_608.onnx  --output ./weights/tiny_3l_v5_11_608.dot --embed_docstring
```

Terveisin, Markus

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use

```
from onnx import shape_inference
inferred_model = shape_inference.infer_shapes(original_model)
```

and find the shape info in `inferred_model.graph.value_info`.

For full doc, see https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/master/docs/ShapeInference.md

Comment: the value_info contains all output, rather than ops wanted whole model final output. this can be retrieved by another method.

Comment: Can we know the onnx model expected input shape, e.g BCHW or BHWC

Answer (score 1):

Hei,

https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorrt
has this feature.

I did

```
onnx2trt yolo_tiny_3l.onnx  -t yolo_tiny_3l.onnx.txt -l -v
```

Terveisin, Markus

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java apis to load ONNX model, then get the metadata information from session. Metadata contains the details about input and output dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the .onnx file into [this online ONNX visualiser tool (Netron)](https://netron.app)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `model.graph.output` to print the output shape:

```
from onnx import shape_inference
inferred_model = shape_inference.infer_shapes(original_model)
print(inferred_model.graph.output)
```